# Porque no puedo guardar mas de 4096 caracteres en una string de Delphi 10.1

Tags: string, sqlite, delphi

Estoy inentando construir una string con multiples SQL queries para ejecutarla en una database de SQLite, pero solo me permite almacenar 4096 caracteres en la string, he probado con AnsiStrings pero es la misma cosa.

Estoy usando `Delphi Berlin 10.1`
Esta es la seccion de mi codigo

```
for i := 1 to S.Count-1 do
  begin
    //checkeamos que no halla algun tipo de valor faltante en la cadena, estamos comprobando:
    //0,9,9,9,9,1,2,00:00
    D.Clear;
    D.CommaText := s[i];

    //ShowMessage(D[7]);
    if Length(D[7])=4 then
      begin
        Aux:=D[7];
        insert('0', Aux, 1);
        D[7]:=Aux;
      end;
    //ShowMessage(D[7]);
    R[0]:=R[0]+D[0];
    R[1]:=R[1]+D[1];
    R[2]:=R[2]+D[2];
    R[3]:=R[3]+D[3];
    R[4]:=R[4]+D[4];
    //ZQuery1.Close;
    //ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    sqlQuery:= sqlQuery+'Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("'+formatdatetime('yyyy-mm-dd', Fecha)+' '+D[7]+':00","'+D[0]+'","'+D[1]+'","'+D[2]+'","'+D[3]+'","'+D[4]+'");';
    //ZQuery1.SQL.Add(sqlQuery);
    //ZQuery1.ExecSQL;
    //preparamos la consulta
    //0,9,9,9,9,1,2,00:00

  end;
```

Este es el resultado truncado de la string `sqlQuery`:

```
'Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:05:00","1","4","6","5","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:10:00","5","2","1","1","1");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:15:00","9","3","8","5","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:20:00","7","7","8","2","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:25:00","0","1","9","1","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:30:00","1","2","3","5","3");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:35:00","7","9","2","0","6");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:40:00","0","8","0","6","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:45:00","7","6","0","1","2");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:50:00","5","0","7","5","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 00:55:00","9","9","8","7","4");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:00:00","3","7","3","5","7");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:05:00","6","4","2","5","0");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:10:00","2","3","6","5","3");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:15:00","6","7","1","0","0");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:20:00","5","8","1","7","0");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:25:00","1","0","3","3","2");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:30:00","4","7","9","9","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:35:00","1","6","0","9","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:40:00","2","8","6","1","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:45:00","3","8","4","0","1");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:50:00","1","1","2","7","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 01:55:00","3","8","2","3","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:00:00","5","5","8","6","3");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:05:00","2","9","1","9","1");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:10:00","9","5","6","9","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:15:00","0","3","2","6","2");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:20:00","2","2","9","0","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:25:00","1","3","8","7","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:30:00","3","6","6","7","2");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:35:00","8","2","2","6","8");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:40:00","2","5","8","0","6");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:45:00","5","9","0","2","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:50:00","1","2","1","8","4");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 02:55:00","1","9","7","8","4");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:00:00","7","5","5","1","0");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:05:00","7","5","6","5","3");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:10:00","2","1","9","0","2");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:15:00","6","9","0","1","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:20:00","9","4","5","8","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:25:00","5","6","8","5","9");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:30:00","9","3","7","1","1");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:35:00","5","9","4","2","6");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:40:00","7","5","3","5","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:45:00","3","2","4","2","7");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:50:00","4","0","5","7","3");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017-03-26 03:55:00","7","8","9","8","5");Insert Into numbers(Date,A,B,C,D,E) Values("2017...
```

Se trunco al 4096 caracter, alguna manera de arreglar esto?

Comment: Todavia sigues teniendo problemas? ya que el string no deberia fallar en el caracter 4096

Comment: Aun sigo teniendo ese problema, al final tuve que usar un vector para almacenar la string, de alli si la leo sin problemas

Comment: Que raro, probaste asignadole un tamano de manera dinamica con setlength mayor a 4096 haber si hay alguna mejora?

Answer (score 1):

Si estás revisando la variable `sqlQuery` en el debugger de Delphi,existe un límite de 4096 caracteres y es por eso que puedes ver los tres puntos "..." al final del string.

Si escribes el string en un memo o un archivo deberías poder ver todo el contenido.